# How to tell maple that derivative of zero is zero when substituting?

Tags: substitution, symbolic-math, maple, simplification, symbolic-computation

I'm trying to use `subs` in maple to replace derivatives in a longer formula with 0:

```
subs(diff(u(r),r) = 0, formula);
```

It seems that if `formula` only involves first derivatives of `u(r)` this works as I expect. For example,

```
formula := diff(u(r),r);
subs(diff(u(r),r) = 0, formula);
                                        0
```

But if `formula` involves second derivatives I get a `diff(0,r)` in the result that won't go away even when using `simplify`:

```
formula := diff(u(r),r,r);
subs(diff(u(r),r) = 0, formula);
                                         d
                                         -- 0
                                         dr
```

(My actual `formula` is quite long involving first and second derivatives of two variables. I know that all derivatives with respect to a certain variable are 0 and I'd like to remove them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the `simplify` command with so-called side-relations.

```
formula := diff(u(r),r,r) + 3*cos(diff(u(r),r,r))
           + diff(u(r),r) + x*(4 - diff(u(r),r,r,r)):

simplify( formula, { diff(u(r),r) = 0 } );

                               3 + 4 x

formula2 := diff(u(r,s),s,s) + 3*cos(diff(u(r,s),r,r))
            + diff(u(r,s),r) + x*(4 - diff(u(r,s),r,s,r,r)):

simplify( formula2, { diff(u(r,s),r) = 0 } );

                          /  2         \      
                          | d          |      
                      3 + |---- u(r, s)| + 4 x
                          |   2        |      
                          \ ds         /
```

[edit] I forgot to answer your additonal query about why you got `d/dr 0` before. The answer is because you used `subs` instead of 2-argument `eval`. The former does purely syntactic substitution, and doesn't evaluate the result. The latter is the one that people often need, without knowing it, and does "evaluation at a (particular) point".

```
formulaA := diff(u(r),r,r):

subs(diff(u(r),r) = 0, formulaA);

                          d   
                         --- 0
                          dr  

%; # does an evaluation

                           0

eval(formulaA, diff(u(r),r) = 0);

                           0

formulaB := diff(u(r,s),s,r,r,s):

eval(formulaB, diff(u(r,s),r) = 0);

                           0
```

You can see that any evaluation of those `d/dr 0` objects will produce 0. But it's is often better practice to use 2-argument eval than it is to do `eval(subs(...))`.  People use `subs` because it sounds like "substitution", I guess, or they see others use it. Sometimes `subs` is the right tool for the job, so it's important to know the difference.

Comment: This works for me. I'd still like to know where theses d/dr 0 come from and how I _would_ get rid of them.

Comment: Ok, I added a note about `subs`.